# Extract Text from String in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Help with a formula to extract text clips out of strings. Turning

- SP BILL(DL/ON-SITE CONT) into DL/ON CONT
- ST MISC(TRAVEL) into TRAVEL

I'm having trouble removing "-SITE" from one cell without ruining the other. Here's what I have so far...

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1,FIND("(",A1)+1)-1-FIND("(",A1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, updated to verify the cell in A1 is not blank and contains both ( and ) characters:

```
=IF(OR(ISERR(FIND("(",A1)),ISERR(FIND(")",A1)),ISBLANK(A1)),"",SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1),"-SITE",""))
```

Comment: This results in "bad value" for empty cells. @Raystafarian was onto something with the IFs, but perhaps wrap this in `IF(LEN(A1)>0, {formula},"")` (etc) is the simplest. (But won't return anything if no parens)

Comment: Updated to verify cell content is not blank and also contains both left and right parenthesis (to keep the FIND() functions from failing)

Answer (score 1):

Close, [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) is your friend -

```
=IF(LEN(A1)<>LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-SITE","")),MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-SITE",""),FIND("(",SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-SITE",""))+1,FIND(")",A1,FIND("(",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-SITE",""))+1)-1-FIND("(",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-SITE",""))-5),MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,FIND(")",A1,FIND("(",A1)+1)-1-FIND("(",A1)))
```

Actually, after finally getting that right, I don't consider SUBSTITUTE a friend any longer. The above answer is much better friends with SUBSTITUTE than mine is.