# How do I extract text between second quotation and first comma?

Tags: worksheet-function

The text string is

```
"Xie,Jianhui" "3246 S. 112 st., Milwaukee, WI 53202" M231
```

I need to extract `3246 S. 112 st`. into its own cell.

I can't figure out the correct function combo to use in Excel. Help?

Comment: I see three quotes before and it is the second comma in the string.  Are they always that way?

Comment: Yes, all entries in the sheet are exactly the same.

Comment: If they format and string length is the same, you can use the left() function. You could also use mid() or find(). P.S. I hope that's not a real person's name and address...

Comment: Also, see https://superuser.com/questions/1043046/extract-text-from-string-in-excel?rq=1

Comment: Please Edit the question, adding tags for microsoft-excel and the specific version you're working with.  The answers available may change depending on version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Find(Substitute()) to find the third `"` and then find the first `,` after that to use in a MID.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","}}}",3))+1,FIND(",",REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","}}}",3))+1,"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing- that worked! Thank you So Much!

Comment: @Struggling1 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.